# Llenar matrices con datos personales

Tags: python, array-bidimensional, fórmulas-de-matriz

Tengo que crear una matriz para llenar una tabla que contenga los datos que el usuario ingresa(nombre,edad,años experiencia laboral y nivel educativo).

```
from tabulate import tabulate 
x=int(input("¿Cuántos trabajadores hay? "))
aspirantes=[[0 for i in range(4)]for j in range(x)]
for j in range(0,x):  
  aspirantes[0][j]=input("nombres","edad","experiencia","niveleducativo")
  aspirantes[1][j]=nombres[i],edad[i],experiencia[i],niveleducativo[i]
  print(tabulate(aspirantes,showindex=["nombres","edad","experiencia","niveleducativo"], tablefmt="grid"))
```

Estaba haciendo esto pero no me da, se que al llenar la matriz esta mal pero no se como arreglarlo.

Comment: Hola Ana! Hay varias preguntas en el sitio sobre `input()` y rellenar matrices! Si les hechas un vistazo seguro que te ayudarán con tu problema :)

Answer (score 0):

En Python no es necesario inicializar "matrices". De hecho no existen matrices, si no otras [estructuras de datos](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), que pueden ser incluso más potentes: listas, tuplas, diccionarios y conjuntos. El concepto, visto desde la consola, es algo así:

```
>>> aspirantes = [] # Define la variable aspirantes como lista
>>> fila = ['Jorge', 35, 10, 'Secundaria'] # Lista con datos
>>> aspirantes.append(fila) # agregar la "fila" a la lista principal
>>> aspirantes
[['Jorge', 35, 10, 'Secundaria']] # Lista, o matriz, 1x4
>>> # También se puede agregar una lista, o "fila", directamente:
>>> aspirantes.append(['Luis', 28, 4, 'Universidad'])
>>> aspirantes
[['Jorge', 35, 10, 'Secundaria'], ['Luis', 28, 4, 'Universidad']] # Lista 2x4
```

Como puedes observar, la lista `aspirantes` **se expande automáticamente** a medida que le vas metiendo datos.

Traduciendo ese concepto, junto con el problema en código, quedaría algo como:

```
x = int(input("¿Cuántos trabajadores hay? "))
aspirantes = []
for i in range(x): # Si empieza desde 0, no es necesario ponerlo.
    print(f"DATOS DEL TRABAJADOR {i+1}")
    nombre = input("Nombre: ")
    edad = int(input("Edad: "))
    experiencia = input("Experiencia: ")
    nivelducativo = input("Nivel educativo: ")
    aspirantes.append([nombre, edad, experiencia, nivelducativo])
```

En este punto `aspirantes` será una "matriz" con los datos suministrados, lo puedes comprobar agregando un:

```
print(aspirantes)
```

Ahora solo te falta formatear los datos para presentarlos en pantalla.